# Irreducibility of polynomial in $\Bbb F_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that $x^5+2x^3+2x^2+2 \in \mathbb{F}_3$ is irreducible.

It's possible to prove this by showing that $f$ doesn't have any roots in $\Bbb F_3$ and that it isn't the product of irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$.

However, this seems to be quite a lot of work considering you first have to make a list of all irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$ over $\Bbb F_3$.

Is there an easier criteria or an easier way to proof the irreducibility of such a polynomial over a finite field (also in general)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a list of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $2$
over $\Bbb F_3$ and check that they are not a factor of $x^5+2x^3+2x^2+2$. The list is very short, namely
$$
x^2 + 1, x^2 + x - 1, x^2 - x - 1.
$$
None of them is a factor (use division).